# how to create a startup script for minecraft

Tags: server, minecraft, startup-applications

I own a vps in which I run various servers from.
One of those things is a Minecraft server. Recently I also installed a teamspeak server following a tutorial. This server however started up automatically on boot and would run even if I did not have an ssh window open running the process. I then attempted to create a similar start up script for my Minecraft server. However I could not do it successfully. I looked up the formatting codes and instructions on the official help page, but when I boot up the Minecraft server it does not auto start like the team speak server. Note: I know screen is an option however I prefer not to use it. The startupscript for team speak was placed in the init.d folder and now runs as long as the server is up despite if I am connected to it or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue when I was setting up a minecraft server on Debian. The following advice should apply to Ubuntu as well.

There are several scripts available. The [minecraft wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Server_startup_script) has a list at the bottom linking to some popular scripts. However, I'd personally recommend [Athenus' minecraft init script](https://github.com/Ahtenus/minecraft-init), which also contains some nice features like world backup and log rotation. It uses screen like many other scripts, but to be honest I think that's a good thing, because that way you can always attach to the console of your server if you ever need it.

Alternatively, you can write your own init script, by using [something like this](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Server_startup_script) as a template. You just need to tweak the `start` and `stop` procedures, which shouldn't be that difficult if you have a bit of experience with the terminal.